# Deleting old files using cron job in Linux

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, cron

I was setting up a cron job where I wanted to delete log files older than 1 day. The command to do this is as below. I am doing this on a AWS Linux EC2 instance.

```
find /var/log/tomcat8/ -mindepth 1 -mtime +1 -delete
```

But what I want to achieve is I want to exclude `.log` files from getting deleted and want to just delete the files with `.gz` extension. Can any body let me know how I achieve that exclusion in find command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `-name` flag to your `find` command like:

```
find /var/log/tomcat8/ -mindepth 1 -mtime +1 -name "*.gz" -delete
```

This should isolate it to finding only older `.gz` files. To add additional options (like another filename type to look for), use the `-o` switch which acts like an 'OR' statement on your options. So, something like:

```
find /var/log/tomcat8/ -mindepth 1 -mtime +1 -name "*.gz" -o -name "*.log" -delete
```

Comment: How will I achieve multiple extension here? for example if I want to delete .gz and .out too?

Comment: Also I get this warning "find: warning: you have specified the -mindepth option after a non-option argument -name, but options are not positional (-mindepth affects tests specified before it as well as those specified after it).  Please specify options before other arguments."

Comment: Hrm, I haven't run into that error before. What OS are you running this on? Also, you might try removing the `-mindepth +1` argument, as I don't think it's really necessary, here.